# terminate handler that throw exception

Tags: c++

We assume following code:

```
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set_terminate([]{throw runtime_error("");});
    throw runtime_error("oops");
}
```

> N3797, §18.8.3.1 [terminate.handler] /2: Required behavior: A
>   terminate_handler shall terminate execution of the program without
>   returning to the caller.

It's undefinied behaviour. what will happen in fact?

Comment: Anything can happen with UB, your fridge may explode.

Comment: It's undefinied. Therefore, why was it aborted?

Comment: Nasal demons, nasal demons everywhere!

Comment: @dsaads _"It's undefinied. Therefore, why was it abort?"_ That may depend on how it's implemented by your toolchain.

Comment: [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) means your whole program is ill-formed and its behavior is, well, *undefined*. There is no way to say what will happen.

Comment: @JBL An [appropriate link](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) would have been helpful! ;) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I supposed anyone would have this reference in mind and thus no need for it ;)

Comment: @JBL 1st time I heard about that term (in ~30yrs of programming practice now). But a good metaphor indeed! I often refer to _Schrödinger's cat_ when explaining UB to newbies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's undefinied behaviour. what will happen in fact?

You don't know.

You could examine the resultant machine code to determine what will actually happen on a given platform, but don't.  UB means you are off the grid, as far as the C++ Standard could happen.  The next time you patch your compiler, your linker, glibc or a million other things, you could get completely different behavior.  You could even get different behavior from run-to-run.

There are few "nevers" in programming, but I will commit to **never deliberately write and rely on the behavior of Undefined Behavior**

Comment: +1 for the concluding comment.